# How to trigger an event upon execution of a raw query in Oracle

Tags: database, oracle

I need to trigger an event upon a change in the value of a certain field in the table. The issue is, since there are multiple stakeholders, they directly execute the raw query on DB- and don't necessarily do it via code. Any directions on the same?

Comment: You should post with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this sql to create a trigger that will fire if any selected column in updated on a table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER schema.trigger_name
   ON schema.tablename
   AFTER UPDATE
AS BEGIN
    IF UPDATE (column) 
    BEGIN
        your event
    END 
END
```